# how reliable is os.cpu_count()?

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

I am using this method in one of my applications. Should one be wary of it returning None/0 or raising error in some operating systems?

I know that os.stat(path) might return some dummy 0s if info is not available.

Answer (score 0):

The nice thing about open-source projects like Python is that you can check the source when you're not sure how something works!

From searching for cpu_count in the [Python repo](https://github.com/python/cpython), it appeared that `os.cpu_count()` is defined in C, rather than pure python:

```
#define OS_CPU_COUNT_METHODDEF    \
    {"cpu_count", (PyCFunction)os_cpu_count, METH_NOARGS, os_cpu_count__doc__},
```

Looking at the [C source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d5d9e81ce9a7efc5bc14a5c21398d1ef6f626884/Modules/posixmodule.c#L11941), it appears that it could return `None` if the operating system doesn't support the syscall to find number of processors in the current context.  I'd expect this to be quite rare.